# Rails Ruport using SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, report, ruport

Guys I'm using Ruport gem for Ruby Reporting, I gone through basic coding and configuration as follows

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_reportable
end
```

and in IRB console i tried as follows

```
irb(main):001:0> puts Project.report_table
```

and it's working fine to me.

Problem is instead of Model, how to write my own queries with SQL and add that to Ruport table object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this in **Ruport** API

So, Instead of using Model directly for reporting like this

```
irb(main):001:0> puts Project.report_table
```

We can write our SQL queries to model like this,

```
irb(main):001:0> puts Project.report_table_by_sql("SELECT * FROM projects")
```

what I need was this syntax

```
report_table_by_sql
```